# changing the color of items in matching lists

Tags: javascript, arrays, events

Basically I have two html strings:

```
a = "Cowboys, Eagles, Redskins, Giants"
b = "Jets, Cowboys, Patriots, Eagles"
```

I want to change the color attribute of the matching items. I have tried making them into arrays, cycling through a and checking if each element is in b, but once I found the matching elements, I had to make it back into an HTML string to print it. How do I search for the matching terms within the string and set just those subsections to a different color? Does that approach make sense, or does anyone have something better?

Thanks

Comment: How do you visualize those strings? JS strings doesn't have any color, they are literally invisible for users

Comment: as text in an html <td> within a larger table. it is the html text that i need to chagne the color of

Comment: so you have 2 rows with values as 1 value per cell?

Comment: so there is a table row with two <td> there is 1 list in each of them

Comment: Can you set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your current code?

Comment: .. please include the variables you are using.

Comment: if this helps... http://jsfiddle.net/qUYpN/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should do what you need](http://jsfiddle.net/qUYpN/8/).  I tried to follow what you were asking for as closely as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of matching back and forth, you can just build string while comparing.

[Will it work for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/qUYpN/7/)